# CSS Less - Define a class encapsulated in other class

Tags: css, less

This is what I need to achieve with CSS Less: I need define a class encapsulated in other class.

***CSS***

```
.class1{ . . .}
.class1 .class2{ . . .}
```

***LESS***

In Less I know how to define this:

```
.class1{&.class2{. . .}}
```

But this is equal to this

```
.class1{}
.class1.class2{}
```

How can I define the first CSS example with Less?

Comment: "&" this will going to classes together, what you need is nesting as shown by @Matt S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply leave out the `&`, which [references the parent selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules).

```
.class1{
    .class2{. . .} 
}
```